# Disable UIWebView default scrolling behavior using objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I know you can use a javascript to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
touchMove = function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
}
```

Is there a way to do the same using objective-c?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this...

```
UIView * v = [[webView subviews] lastObject];
[v setScrollEnabled:NO];
[v bounces:NO];
```

**EDIT:** Added checks to original answer based on comment below

```
UIView * v = [[webView subviews] lastObject];
if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]) {
    if ([v respondsToSelector:@selector(setScrollEnabled]) {
        [v setScrollEnabled:NO];
    }
    if ([v respondsToSelector:@selector(bounces)]) {
        [v bounces:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea. `UIWebView`'s internal view hierarchy can change at any OS update. At least check to see if the subview responds to those methods before calling them.

Comment: can you explain what this means? is lastObject the <html> element?

Comment: @Melina the last subview of the UIWebView, @rpetrich added the check, thx

Comment: the last subview of UIWebView is the actual content area? right?

Comment: A couple notes.. It's overkill to check for the specific methods because you already know it's a UIScrollView, so you know what methods it'll have. Also, it's `setBounces:NO`, not `bounces:NO`.

Comment: It all works without setBounces: , setScrollEnabled: is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can also access the scrollView like this :

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
webView.scrollView.bounces = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @aaron-saunders and @matt-rix 's answers, here's what works best for me :

```
UIView *v = [[webView subviews] lastObject];
if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    [v setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use complex methods. You can access Scrollview of webview directly as below.

web_view.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;