# Disable scrolling the webview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable UIWebView default scrolling behavior using objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800441/disable-uiwebview-default-scrolling-behavior-using-objective-c)

I want to disable my webview scrolling, I have checked all property but I could not find any property which is useful for me , if this is possible please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: `[webview.scrollview setScrollingEnabled:NO]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this code which may be helpful

```
UIView* row = nil;
for(row in webView.subviews){
    if([row isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]){
        UIScrollView* scrollRow = (UIScrollView*) row;
        scrollRow.scrollEnabled = NO;
        scrollRow.bounces = NO;
        scrollRow.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
for(UIView *scrl in webView.subviews){
    if([row isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]){
        UIScrollView* scrollView = (UIScrollView*) scrl;
        // stop scrolling
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

       //stop bounceback of webView..
      scrollView.bounces = NO;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this it works fine; `webDescription` is a `UIWebView` object.

```
[[webDescription.subviews lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: Like with Narayana's answer, this is a very bad idea.  You do not know the internal view layout of Apple's UI elements, and they can change this at any time which would lead to a crash in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[[[yourWebViewObject subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: No, do not do this.  Relying on the internal ordering of subviews in Apple's UI elements is a recipe for disaster, and will most likely lead to crashes on future OS updates.